# Using This Week/Last Week for an automatically running report

Tags: sql, date, datetime, daterangepicker, sqlparameter

I have set the dates in the parameter as below, but I'm lost with the next bit... what I want is;

If @TodayDayOfWeek < 5   (so it is Monday - Thursday) then run last week's dates (from @Startoflastweek - @endoflastweek)
else use this weeks date range

```
DECLARE @TodayDayOfWeek INT

DECLARE @EndOfThisWeek datetime

DECLARE @StartOfThisWeek datetime

DECLARE @EndOfPrevWeek DateTime

DECLARE @StartOfPrevWeek DateTime

SET @TodayDayOfWeek = datepart(dw, GetDate())

set @EndOfThisWeek =  DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 4)

set @StartOfThisWeek =  DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), 0)

SET @EndOfPrevWeek = DATEADD(dd, -@TodayDayOfWeek, GetDate())

SET @StartOfPrevWeek = DATEADD(dd, -(@TodayDayOfWeek+6), GetDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server and this is SProc

```
CASE WHEN @TodayDayOfWeek < 5 THEN
BEGIN
  -- YOUR LOGIC
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
  -- ELSE LOGIC
END
```